# r repeat sequence number sequence while keeping the order of the sequence

Tags: r

I want repeat a sequence for specific length:

Sequence is 1:4 and I want to repeat the sequence till number of rows in a data frame.

Lets say length of the data frame is `24`

I tried following:

```
test <- rep(1:4, each=24/4)
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Lengthwise this is fine but i want to retain the sequence 
`1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4.....`

Comment: Practically the first two examples in `?rep` helpfile.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `times` instead of `each`

```
rep(1:4, times=24/4)
[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just pass it without any argument and it takes the `times` by default

```
rep(1:4, 24/4)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```